# Why does int give me a different value when the input values are all integers?

Tags: java

```
    public class d333 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
double money = 1 ; 
int day = 1 ; 
while(day > 30) { 
money *= 2; 
System.out.printf("After day %d you have %.2f\n", day, money); 
    } 
    } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the sign of `>` to `<` or `<=`. Furthermore, you are never incrementing the `day` variable so it will always be day 1 i.e. the loop will never terminate. Lastly, since you start with an integer and are multiplying by an integer you are right in that there is no need for having `money` be of type `double`.

Try something like this:

```
class D333 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int money = 1;
        int day = 1;
        while (day <= 30) {
            money *= 2;
            System.out.printf("After day %d you have $%d\n", day, money);
            day += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
After day 1 you have $2
After day 2 you have $4
After day 3 you have $8
After day 4 you have $16
After day 5 you have $32
After day 6 you have $64
After day 7 you have $128
After day 8 you have $256
After day 9 you have $512
After day 10 you have $1024
After day 11 you have $2048
After day 12 you have $4096
After day 13 you have $8192
After day 14 you have $16384
After day 15 you have $32768
After day 16 you have $65536
After day 17 you have $131072
After day 18 you have $262144
After day 19 you have $524288
After day 20 you have $1048576
After day 21 you have $2097152
After day 22 you have $4194304
After day 23 you have $8388608
After day 24 you have $16777216
After day 25 you have $33554432
After day 26 you have $67108864
After day 27 you have $134217728
After day 28 you have $268435456
After day 29 you have $536870912
After day 30 you have $1073741824
```

Comment: No problem @ErionMalo if my answer solved your question could you click the green check mark / tick to mark it correct? On the grind for 10k rep.